# python ctime of a directory referenced by a symbolic link

Tags: python, directory, symlink, stat, ctime

we have a directory `directory` and a symlink pointing to it `symlink -> directory`. Symlink is updated periodically (recreated) but the directory is updated much less often.

Problem: find out what was the directory update time (ctime) using python.

Approach: using os.stat, documentation says it follows symlinks (in python 2).

Debug:

```
ls -lah symlink    # gives me 8:04
ls -lahd symlink   # gives me 8:04
ls -lahd symlink/  # gives me 6:55
ls -lahd directory # gives me 6:55
```

6.55 is what i want to get using python os.stat

in python

```
from stat import S_ISREG, S_ISDIR, S_ISLNK
import os
f = 'symlink/'
st=os.stat(f)
print(S_ISLNK(st.st_mode), S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)
```

I get `False, True` (by the way, the same if i run it on `f='symlink'`)
That's it it says it's a directory
However, 
`st[-1]` (which corresponds to `st_ctime`) will give me an equivalent of 8:04

Question: 
How to query in python ctime of a directory having a symlink to it?

Thank you

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, however I get `6:55` on ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6. What's your os, and which python version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Python 2.7.12